# Is the pretrained model selected at random when not specified from transformers

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, nlg

I am trying to implement a QA system using models from huggingface. One thing I do not understand is, when I don't specify which pre-trained model I am using for question-answering, is the model chosen at random?

```
from transformers import pipeline

# Allocate a pipeline for question-answering

question_answerer = pipeline('question-answering')
question_answerer({

     'question': 'What is the name of the repository ?',
     'context': 'Pipeline have been included in the huggingface/transformers repository'

})
```

Output:

`{'score': 0.5135612454720828, 'start': 35, 'end': 59, 'answer': 'huggingface/transformers'}`

I know how to specify a model by adding the name of the model (bert-base-uncased for example) as a model parameter, but which one is it using when you are not specifying anything? Does it use a combination of all models on huggingface? I could not find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is not chosen randomly. Ever task in the pipeline selects the appropriate model whichever is close to the task. A model which is closely trained on the objective of your desired task and dataset is chosen. For example, `sentiment-analysis` pipeline can chose the model trained on SST task.

Likewise, for `question-answering`, it chooses `AutoModelForQuestionAnswering` class with `distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad` as the default model, as SQUAD dataset is associated with question answering task.

To get the list, you can look at the variable `SUPPORTED_TASKS` [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/23e5a36ee670150a632cfa8004de2c7244f305aa/src/transformers/pipelines/__init__.py)